# Unit Test ASP.NET CORE 2.1 System.NullReferenceException response

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

Делал модульные тесты для проекта ASP.NET CORE . Через Moq делал заглушки... Вообщем в коде самого теста всё как надо. Ошибка `NullReferenceException` возникает при вызове строки `Response.Cookies.Append(userName, account.ExternalId);`. Вот пример кода контроллера `LoginController`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string userName) {
    var account = await _db.FindByUserNameAsync(userName);
    Response.Cookies.Append(userName, account.ExternalId);
    return Ok();
}
```

Вот пример кода из теста:

```
public async Task WhenLoginUserBobNameThenPageReturnOkAndCookieExist() {
    string userName = "Имя пользователя, которое есть в базе данных, 
         хотя это не важно, я же использую mock";
    var db = new Mock<ИнтерфейсБд>();
    var account = new Account() {
        ExternalId = userName,
    };
    db.Setup(repo => repo.FindByUserNameAsync(userName)).ReturnsAsync(account);
    var controller = new LoginController(db.Object);

    var loginResult = await controller.Login(userName);
    //var expected = controller.Request.Cookies[userName];

    Assert.IsType<OkResult>(loginResult);
    Assert.Equal(expected, userName);
}
```

Основная задача теста была проверить, что куки правильно сохранились (это и так понятно, но я новичок и поэтому всё равно хотел затестить), но столкнулся с такой ошибкой. Я так понимаю ошибка вызывается при обращении к полю `Response` - оно равно `null`. Но при сборке проекта сервис работает. Дело в неправильном построении теста. Может надо запускать объект `Startup.cs`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Похоже, дело в строке:

```
db.Setup(repo => repo.FindByUserNameAsync(userName)).ReturnsAsync(account);
```

Здесь вы просите библиотеку Moq при вызове `FindByUserNameAsynс` с определёнными параметрами возвращать определённое значение. Если вы хотите поставить в соответствие конкретное значение, передавайте в качестве параметра константу. В данном случае можно поставить в соответствие любое строковое значение, поскольку метод будет вызван ровно один раз и у нас не будет нескольких вариантов. Любой значение записывается как `It.IsAny<string>()`:

```
db.Setup(repo => repo.FindByUserNameAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(account);
```

После этого изменения метод начнёт подставляться при любом значение параметра и будет возвращать существующее значение `account`.

**UPDATE**

Дописываю ответ после комментария. Если речь идёт о поле `Request`, то тестировать его изменение можно несколькими способами.

Способ номер **один**: если свойство `Request` публичное и изменяемое, мы можем установить его значение перед тестом.

```
var controller = new LoginController(db.Object);
controller.Request = new HttpRequest { … };
```

Этот метод не сработает в нашем случае, потому что свойство `Request` только для чтения. Мы могли бы попробовать способ номер **два**: если свойство только для чтения, но оно виртуальное, библиотека Moq может его *переопределить*.

```
var controllerMock = new Mock<LoginController>(db.Object);
```

Здесь возникает проблема: Moq переопределяет свойство `Request`, но также переопределяет и все остальные виртуальные методы. Если бы метод `Login` был виртуальным, мы не могли бы его протестировать.

В этом случае мы должны попросить библиотеку вызывать *старые* методы. Часть методов нам нужна для тестов и мы их должны явно перечислить:

```
controllerMock.SetupGet(x => x.Request)
              .Returns(new HttpRequest { … });
controllerMock.CallBase = true;
```

Невиртуальные методы будут вызываться, как и раньше. Виртуальные тоже будут взываться, как раньше, из-за `CallBase`. Свойство `Request` будет возвращать указанное значение.

Вроде подходящий вариант, но, заглянув в документацию, мы выясняем, что свойство `Request` невиртуальное, и мы не можем его переопределить. Как быть в этом случае?

Если код ваш, то вы можете сделать свойство виртуальным. Если вы при разработке библиотеки покрываете её тестами, все такие неправильные свойства и методы всплывают быстро. Но код базового котроллера `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` не ваш, изменить его вы не можете.

Используем способ **три**: избавимся от прямой зависимости. Добавим в `LoginController` метод:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string userName)
{
    var account = await _db.FindByUserNameAsync(userName);

    StoreUserInCookied(userName, account.ExternalId);

    return Ok();
}


public virtual void StoreUserInCookies(string username, string externalId)
{
    Response.Cookies.Append(username, account.ExternalId);
}
```

Для того, чтобы протестировать такой код, соберём всё, что мы уже знаем:

```
var controllerMock = new Mock<LoginController>(db.Object);
controllerMock.Setup(x => x.StoreUserInCookies("john doe", It.IsAny<string>());
controllerMock.CallBase = true;

. . .

await controllerMock.Object.Login("john doe");
```

Видим, что код не очень простой. Это произошло в том числе и потому, что мы перегрузили наш контроллер ответственностью. Логику складывания пользовательских данных в куки и их извлечения можно вынести совсем в отдельный класс:

```
public class CookieStorage
{
    public virtual void StoreUser(HttpCookie cookie, string name, string id)
    {
        cookie.Append(name, id);
    }

    . . .
}
```

Внедрить такой класс в `LoginController` можно через конструктор. Метод `Login` станет выглядеть так:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string userName)
{
    var account = await _db.FindByUserNameAsync(userName);

    _cookieStorage.StoreUser(Request.Cookie, userName, account.ExternalId);

    return Ok();
}
```

Поскольку мы сделали метод `StoreUser` виртуальным, мы можем использовать его в качестве заглушки.

Здесь у нас получается случай, когда тестирование подсказывает то, как улучшить дизайн системы. К методу `StoreUser` надо написать парный `GetUser`, который, вероятно, будет вызываться из самых разных контроллеров в нескольких местах.

Создав `CookieStorage` мы инкапсулировали логику работы с куками в одном месте и можем вносить согласованные изменения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Дело не в объекте Account. Это показывают следующие изменения в коде контроллера:
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string userName) {
        var account = await _db.FindByUserNameAsync(userName);
        if (account != null) {
        Response.
        Cookies.
        Append(
        userName, 
        account.ExternalId);
}
        return Ok();
    }
Ошибка именно в Response, он равен null. Простите за кривую вставку кода, не знаю как вставлять код в комментарий.

Comment: Вот это фрагмент кода https://pastebin.com/VPXYA9f3 .

Comment: @ПантелеймонАкакков Дописал ответ.